# Characteristic impedance of a trace

Tags: rf

I'm trying design a video transmitter around an 5.8GHz Airwave module. The documentation says the trace to the antenna must have a characteristic impedance of 50 ohms. How do I calculate the characteristic impedance of my trace?

Comment: See the section titled "Sizing the feedline" in [this article](http://colinkarpfinger.com/blog/2010/the-dropouts-guide-to-antenna-design/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a quick rule of thumb for 50 ohms, you want the ratio of the trace width to the height above the ground plane (probably your board thickness) to be around 1.8 with 2-oz copper. With a standard 0.063" thick PCB, that means a trace width around 120 mil. (Fat!)

Formulas for calculating this can be found in various places. If you access to an engineering library, try chapter 4 of High Speed Digital Design by Johnson and Graham. (Equation 4.90 on p. 187 is the key one.)

Here's an online calculator: http://referencedesigner.com/tutorials/si/si_06.php

Comment: Thanks! What happens if the trace doesn't meet this requirement? (e.g. extra noise, reduced transmission distance?) Also, is there any problem with trace length?

Comment: Re width, is this radius or diameter?

Comment: You don't care about length-- characteristic impedance is a measure of the ratio of inductance to capacitance at any point in the trace. Let me think about the effects of missing the 50 ohm target for a minute.

Comment: Width means neither radius not diameter. I'm not sure what you mean with your second comment.

Comment: Well, my PCB program has an input for "Line Width". The line is like a circle being repeatedly drawn along a line, so the radius is the radius of this circle, and the same for diameter. I assume width means the diameter across the line. Radius could mean half the width.

Comment: You want the characteristic impedance to match the source and load impedance, or you'll get reflections back and forth down the line.  With analog video, I think this produces "ghosting"?  But if this is sending something modulated I'm not sure what the effect would be.  Some reduction in efficiency, too, since some energy would be wasted?

Comment: OK, here's my understanding of mismatched characteristic impedance. As a signal passes from source, through the trace, and into a load, the signal is attenuated in the trace, and some signal is reflected at each intersection. With matched impedance, there are no reflections. If the trace is too wide (too much capacitance) *or* too narrow (too much inductance), reflections and attenuation increase.

Comment: Ah, I get the radius-diameter question now. Yes, width means diameter of your line-drawing circle. What PCB program, by the way?

Comment: I use the gEDA PCB package.

Comment: @pingswept, When the line does not match impedance you will have very big problems that will be very dependent on what the distance is. This is quite nasty in general. When you say intersection, I think i know what you mean, this is actually an impedance mismatch.

Comment: I was a little unclear. When I said "You don't care about length," I meant it regarding characteristic impedance, i.e. characteristic impedance is an intrinsic property of a trace; it doesn't accumulate with length like resistance does. When it comes to getting your signal down a trace, you *do* care about length because of signal attenuation (the "big problems" you mentioned). Signal attenuation does increase with length.

Comment: @pingswept, I thought you understood but wanted to note more for others. @ThomasO, if you have a bad match on higher power RF you can easily destroy your transmitter with reflected power. Be careful, RF design is a career field and not something that you just do after 20 minutes of reading.

Comment: You'll need to know the PCB layer stackup used by your manufacturer to determine the height of the trace above the reference plane and the permittivity of the PCB material before using a trace width calculator.